# Why my button work juste one time ? - Android studio

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying tp send sms by clicking a button bt this button is working juste one time.
And i don't know how I can get it so the button can be pressed an infinite amount of time.
Can you please help me to fix that.
this is my code :

```
Button sendBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

}
protected void sendSMSMessage() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+212xxxxxx", null, "Je suis en danger, voici ma localisation : https://goo.gl/maps/xamxKW62p34wWpBU8", null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `else` branch in `sendSMSMessage`, so you are not sending SMS if `SEND_SMS` permission is already granted. You are also not doing anything if you need to show permission rationale, which results in a broken experience.

Overall I would suggest to read carefully the [docs on requesting permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission). It explains both your approach with `onRequestPermissionsResult` as well as the new recommended way of using `ActivityResultContracts`.

Without rewriting your code to the contracts I would fix it like this:

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            // fixme: show explanation 
            // before requesting the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    } else {
        sendSmsImpl();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSmsImpl();
            } else {
                // fixme: explain that it can't send SMS without the permission
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // !!! NOTE: you still need break inside switch/case
            // even with curly braces
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void sendSmsImpl() {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("+212xxxxxx", null, "Je suis en danger, voici ma localisation : https://goo.gl/maps/xamxKW62p34wWpBU8", null, null);
    //todo: use sentIntent argument of sendTextMessage to detect success/error
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```